# How Insert if not exists with parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite

When trying to perform the following instructions I get an error: SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'near 'WHERE': syntax error', operation:'execute', detailID:'2003'. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
                dbStatement.text = "INSERT INTO person (idPerson,image) VALUES (:idPerson,:image) " +
                "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idPerson FROM person WHERE idPerson=:idPerson)";
            dbStatement.parameters[":idPerson"] = person.idPerson; 
            dbStatement.parameters[":image"] = person.image; 
            dbStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `INSERT OR REPLACE person ( ... ) VALUES( ... )`.

Comment: Unfortunately continues to repeat records. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO person (idPerson,image) VALUES (:idPerson,:image)

Comment: Is "idPerson" a PRIMARY key or UNIQUE?

Comment: "idPerson" is not PRIMARY key.

Comment: Can you set it as a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key then? I think that would solve the problem.

Comment: You mean like this: dbStatement.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
     "idPerson INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
     "image BLOB )"; - because it still does not work.

Comment: Yeah, except UNIQUE instead of PRIMARY, because you have a PRIMARY key already